# Is there a way to resize file by setting new position of "end of file" using fstream in C++?

Tags: c++, fstream

We can open a file for input and output, and then read and write to arbitrary positions using `seekg`.

Can one shrink or extend this file by setting the new end of file (without buffering the entire content to another file or to the memory)?

(Is there any way to resize a file pre C++17, by the standard?)

Comment: truncate/ftruncate can resize to an arbitrary size

Comment: @AlexStepanov: But those are POSIX, not portable C++

Comment: @BenVoigt I found portable: std::filesystem::resize_file :) Added in C++17, although I can't say anything about its support by compilers

Comment: @AlexStepanov: Yes that looks like the correct "pure C++" function